# Split a string in python into only two parts starting from the left

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string from `input()` that I would like to only split into two parts with the delimiter as a space, even though a space may occur more than twice.

For instance, if the input string was

```
'acquire Wooden Shield'
```

the resulting list I want would be

```
['acquire', 'Wooden Shield]
```

I would assume this is pretty simple to do, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can take a second parameter that defines how many splits you would like to do. If you only want two elements, you can just split once.

```
>>> s = 'acquire Wooden Shield'
>>> s.split(' ', 1)
['acquire', 'Wooden Shield']
```

> `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])` If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

Answer (score 2):

```
string.split(' ', 1)
```

Second parameter is the number of matches

Reference [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)